# Black Screen on install

Tags: system-installation

I have been trying to install Ubuntu on my dads computer. I can only get this far before a black screen:

[image: Install_1][image: Install_2]

I have tried to use nomodeset with no change. Even if I lock the screen it still goes to sleep. I am not sure what else to do. Any and all feedback is welcome, thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried `acpi=off`?

Comment: No, I will try this next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD (or USB flash drive, if you must)and choose `Try Ubuntu`. BEFORE double-clicking on the Install Ubuntu icon on the desktop, lets check a few settings...

Open `System Settings` from the rightmost icon in the upper panel. Select `Brightness & Lock`. Set `Turn screen off when inactive for` to **NEVER**. Set `lock` to **OFF**.

Next, go back to `All Settings` and choose `Power`. Set `Suspend when inactive for` to **NEVER**.

Close System Settings and now try to install Ubuntu by double-clicking on the Install Ubuntu icon on the desktop.

Keep us posted. Cheers, Al